# How to speed-up regex to search and replace common html/css words

Tags: regex, c++11, pcre

I am using pcre2 to search and remove common css/html in an html page
my problem is that this is a rather slow part in the code.

`((border-spacing|color|font-size|yyyy|zzzz)\s?:.*?;?)`, I am replacing the word with a single space.

for example, `color:blue;` would be replaced by a single space.

I have identified about 30 words I would like to replace and I am searching a string with about 5000 characters.
But I cannot identify why this is slow.

Any suggestions as how I could improve the regex above?

**Edit**: (100% speed improvement)

As per the comments, I removed some greedy searches and some `*?`
`((border-spacing|color|font-size|yyyy|zzzz)[^:]{0,}:[^\;\}]{1,}?[;\}])`

I know that `{0,}` and `{1,}` are the same as `*` and `+` but somehow the speed was ~5% faster without...

It is not exactly the same, but the speed improvement is worth it...

Comment: `.*?;?` is why it is slow. But could you use a CSS parser instead?

Comment: I am not familiar with any css parser, and I am concerned that this might add a lot of overhead to an otherwise 'simple' function.

Comment: If you have a `+` or `*` after the last `)` and it is all in the middle of  a longer pattern, this is prone with catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: I made an edit to remove the `.*?;?`, `*` and `+` the improvement was worth the small difference is result, (actually, I think the original was not quite right anyway). I know that `{0,}` and `{1,}` are the same as `*` and `+` but somehow the speed was ~5% faster without...